# why does my python while loop infinitely?

Tags: python, while-loop

I am trying to do a while loop that execute a function while the verification is not changed.
my code looks like this:

```
from time import sleep

verif = 0
num = 5

def doso(num, verif):
    if num%11 == 0:
        verif += 1

    elif num%14 == 0:
        verif += 1

    print(num)
    return verif

while verif == 0:
    doso(num, verif)
    num += 1
    sleep(1)
```

so for now it run infinitely... i would like if it stoped when it find a multiple of 11 or 14

**its an example

Comment: because the value of `verif` is not changed inside the loop. You probably meant to do `verif = doso(num, verif)`

Comment: `verif += 1` inside the `doso` function creates a local variable, but does not change the global variable defined above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using global variables in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try updating the variable:

```
while verif == 0:
    verif = doso(num, verif)
    num += 1
    sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

To avoid running into an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), note that you do not need `verif` at all. You can simply do:

```
num = 5

while True:
    if num%11 == 0 or num%14 == 0:
      break
    else:
      num += 1
```